# This is a spectacularly slow dataframe join. Why?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm a fan of the Dataframe API over Spark SQL, but something tells me this join is pushing it too far. I've got 32 cores available, but the job is hanging with just one task active, utilising presumably one core of one executor. Both tables in the join are cached, one is 9 GB, on 2 GB.

```
val join = sc_meta
    .join(sd_coverage, 
          (sc_meta("xocs_issn") === sd_coverage("issn") or 
          sc_meta("print_issn") === sd_coverage("issn") or 
          sc_meta("electronic_issn") === sd_coverage("issn") or 
          sc_meta("other_issn") === sd_coverage("issn")) and 
          sc_meta("volume") === sd_coverage("volume") and 
          sc_meta("issue") === sd_coverage("issue"),
          "leftsemi")
join.count
```

Note the 'or' expressions there. Running the join without the or clauses completes in under ten seconds.

Thoughts for rewriting this query, or taking a different strategy?

Comment: I had some problems with joins with "or" conditions too. I think Spark does a full cartesian product and apply the or conditions as a filter (I'm not sure though).

Comment: Run `join.explain()` and you will know if Spark can push predicate down or it's making cartesian with filtering

Comment: can't you express your or-s with union over multiple joins?(and maybe reduce afterwards to remove duplicates)?
if every join will take 10 sec, then you'll have your results after 1min or a bit more.

Comment: Thanks. So running join.explain() showed that Catalyst uses SortMergeJoin, which resulted in highly skewed partitioning. This explains why I had one task running at the end - the majority of the data was in one partition. Taking Igor's strategy results in a much quicker query run time, although it's more verbose.